# missing EOF at 'Say'

Tags: xtext

I am writing grammar to recognize following input

```
Say Hello Boss  
Hello friend
```

Here is my complete grammar

grammar `org.xtext.example.second.MyDsl` with `org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals`

generate myDsl `"http://www.xtext.org/example/second/MyDsl"`

Example:

```
statements+=Statement*;
```

Statement:

```
(IDLABEL)? Directives;
```

Directives:

```
TAG1 | TAG2 | TAG3 | TAG4;

TAG1: tag=('Hi'|'Hello') IDLABEL;

TAG2: tag=('Tag2') IDLABEL;

TAG3: tag=('Tag3') IDLABEL;

TAG4: tag=('Tag4') IDLABEL;

STRING_OPERANDS hidden(WS):
    ("*"|UNQUOTED|QUOTED)+;

terminal QUOTED:
    "'" ( '\\' . /* 'b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'u'|'"'|"'"|'\\' */ | !('\\'|"'") )* "'";

terminal UNQUOTED:
    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9' | '-' | '*' | "/" | "\\" | '(' | ')' | '$' | '=' |'@' |'.' | '"' |'#'|'+'|"'"|'<'|'>')*;

terminal IDLABEL:
    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9'|'='|'#')*;
```

For the input, Say Hello Boss
I am getting an error `"missing EOF at Say"`

and for the input Hello Boss
I am getting an error `"mismatched input 'Boss' expecting RULE_IDLABEL"`

*What is wrong with this grammar?*

Answer (score 1):

`Boss` matches both the rule `IDLABEL` and `UNQUOTED`. In cases where two rules can match the current input and both rules match the same prefix, the tokenizer uses the rule that comes first. So the input `Boss` produces an `UNQUOTED` token, not an `IDLABEL` token.

In fact all valid `IDLABEL`s are also valid `UNQUOTED`s, so you'll never get any `IDLABEL` tokens.

To fix this, you can change the order of `UNQUOTED` and `IDLABEL`, so that `IDLABEL` comes first.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yes, I had observed that changing the order of UNQUOTED and IDLABEL will solve the issue.  But my question is, I have not used QUOTED, UNQUOTED and STRING_OPERANDS as part of grammar. Then how it is influencing parsing?

Comment: @Ningareddy The tokenizer works independently of the parser. It does not care which tokens are expected by the parser at a given position. It simply goes through all terminal rules and produces a token for the rule that finds the longest match (using order as the tie breaker). The parser then works on the tokens generated by the tokenizer and if the tokenizer didn't generate the tokens that the parser needs, the parser can't succeed.